# Adding jars causes getFragments() to be undefined

Tags: android, jar

I just added these [four jars](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/tree/master/library/libs) to use the ShowcaseView library. Now I get all these `getFragments()` and `getChildFragmentManager()`  is undefined. Any solutions to this? Or is my project targeting a too high Sdk version?

Answer (score 1):

The `android-support-v4.jar` you added is an older version and either replaced or is overriding the support library you had already included.  Replace this .jar with with the newest version of the support library and it should fix your issue.

Comment: I have android-support-v7-appcompat imported. Removing the android-support-v4.jar didn't do anything though.

Comment: The robolectric jar is giving me problems. If I remove it the errors go away

Answer (score 0):

erase the imports your using, in the classes getting errors, then hover them and see if you get"fix project setup" option. if not re-import, if you get option, scroll down in the fix project setup box, and find the jars related to that particular import and click it. i had similar errors switching between andengine gles2 and anchor center... if there are any classes in those jars with the same name, even though you have the package, eclipse gets confused, and will give you compile errors.

Comment: For 'find the jars related to that particular import', i have numerous options here; Add archive... Add project.... One of them is the robolectric jar (which I mentioned in a comment on the other answer). Should I add that one?

Comment: yeah dont add the project add the archive.

Comment: then make sure you re-import everything you need, and clean the project